# Can I help Tor if I just have webspace?

Tags: help

I'm thinking about how I can help Tor and its users. However I don't own big servers and also don't want to run a relay from my home. The only thing I have up to now is some private website. Is there anything I can do to help out?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, you could set up a [web site mirror](https://www.torproject.org/getinvolved/mirrors.html.en) for [torproject.org](http://torproject.org). It requires approximately 8 GB of disk space. Detailed instructions for setting up a mirror are [available](https://www.torproject.org/docs/running-a-mirror.html.en).

Second, you could add [flash-proxy badges](https://crypto.stanford.edu/flashproxy/) to the web sites you run. This is done by simply adding an `iframe` to your HTML source. By including the badge, you can easily help users in censored countries.

Answer (score 5):

The [volunteer page](https://www.torproject.org/getinvolved/volunteer.html.en) on the Tor website lists several easy things you can do to help the Tor Project. A few easy ones are below.

- If you're willing to spend a tiny bit of money (~20 USD per month) you can set up a Tor bridge relay via [Tor Cloud](https://cloud.torproject.org/).
- Know any languages that Tor should be in? You can help with [translating tor](https://www.torproject.org/getinvolved/translation.html.en).
- And of course, [advocacy](https://www.torproject.org/getinvolved/volunteer.html.en#Advocacy) is always good (and you can use the web resources you already own).
- You can also [mirror](https://www.torproject.org/docs/running-a-mirror.html.en) the Tor website and/or downloads.
- Finally, you can help by donating a bit of bandwidth to seed the torrent for [Tails](https://tails.boum.org/download/index.en.html#index2h1) (though this really isn't that necessary... the seed/peers ratio is currently 418/25).

Comment: Just wanted to add that Tor Cloud will cost a bit more than ~3 USD per month (more like ~20 USD per month, depending on the region you decide to put the Tor Cloud instance in) if you do not qualify for the AWS free tier.

Comment: @Runa Oh, I didn't realize that; thanks. I don't know about the free tier, but I must have qualified for it as it only cost me about ~3.50 or so back when I ran one.

Answer (score 3):

> However I don't own big servers and also don't want to run a relay
>   from my home.

Probably, if you already use Tor from your home, and you have an external IP address, or may do port forwarding for a web server, you can easy help Tor with a **middle relay**, not an exit relay. This is simpler than even deploying a web mirror.

Meaning, your relay will not be banned by Google or any other companies who dislike Tor exit nodes.

Simple configuration:

```
# cat > /usr/local/etc/tor/torrc << EOF
SocksPort 9050
Log notice file /usr/local/var/log/tor/notices.log
RunAsDaemon 1
DataDirectory /usr/local/var/lib/tor
ControlPort 9051
ORPort 9001
Nickname relay
RelayBandwidthRate  1 MB
RelayBandwidthBurst 5 MB
ContactInfo anonymous anonymous@mail.com
DirPort 9030
ExitPolicy reject *:*
EOF
```

You can specify the relay bandwidth to gain optimal speed for your connection.

`ExitPolicy reject *:*` - set your relay as a middle in the Tor network. That way you increase the ***security*** of Tor network. In my humble opinion, ***this is the best way to help the Tor project***, if you only have an Internet connection.

Start your relay with this configuration:

```
# tor -f /usr/local/etc/tor/torrc
```

Answer (score 2):

Even if you cannot contribute any sort of network resource, you can still contribute money that will be used to pay operating costs for running relays. See, for example, https://www.torservers.net/

Comment: For a list of others see the question ["Which exit node providers can I financially support to run nodes on my behalf?"](http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/240/which-exit-node-providers-can-i-financially-support-to-run-nodes-on-my-behalf)