# Which exit node providers can I financially support to run nodes on my behalf?

Tags: exit-relays

This [blog post from 2011](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/support-tor-network-donate-exit-node-providers) mentions a few organisations that accept donations to run Tor exit nodes. What all organisations are there that accept donations to run exit nodes on my behalf?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's actually been an explosion of non-profits lately that are organized for running exit relays. In rough order of appearance on the scene:

- [Zwiebelfreunde](https://www.torservers.net/), aka torservers.net, is the original organization formed for this purpose, and they still operate the most capacity in the Tor network (Germany).
- The [Swiss Privacy Foundation](http://privacyfoundation.ch/) has been running Tor exits for many years now (Switzerland).
- [NoiseTor](http://noisetor.net/) is a project of the San Francisco-based Noisebridge 501c3 non-profit (USA).
- [Föreningen för Digitala Fri- och Rättigheter](https://www.dfri.se/index.en) (DFRI) is a Swedish non-profit that runs several large exit relays (Sweden).
- [Frënn vun der Ënn](http://www.enn.lu/) runs some large exits as well (Luxembourg).
- [Nos Oignons](http://nos-oignons.net/) is a French non-profit started by Lunar et al to run fast exits (France).
- [Hart Voor Internetvrijheid](https://www.hartvoorinternetvrijheid.nl/) is just starting up, organized by some of our friends in and around Amsterdam (Netherlands).

---

In addition, organizations like the German [Chaos Computer Club](https://www.ccc.de/) have run fast reliable exits for many years, and would welcome donations and help.

Keep an eye on [Zwiebelfreunde's partners list](https://www.torservers.net/partners.html) for new ones.